# I can't get the return key in my UITextField's to work

Tags: ipad, ios4, uitextfield, return, xcode4.2

I can't get the return key in my `UITextField's` to work!
I have quite a lot of `UITextField's` so can someone give a short bit of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
- (IBAction)textFieldDoneEditing:(id)sender 
{ 
     [sender resignFirstResponder];
}
```

You will have to connect this to all the text fields you have. Use the `Did End On Exit` option when connecting to the `File's Owner`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a lot of text fields and you want the return key to bring up the next textfield. So the user can enter data quickly. Then set the set the delegate for each textfield to be your view controller with

```
textField.delegate = self;
```

make sure your view controller adopts the UITextFieldDelegate protocol by putting this in the interface declaration

```
<UITextFieldDelegate>
```

then use the textFieldShouldReturn method

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    if (textField == self.Field1) {
        [self.Field2 becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    else if (textField == self.Field2) {
        [self.Field3 becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    else if (textField == self.Field3) {
        [self.Field4 becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    else if (textField == self.Field4) {
        [self.Field5 becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    else if (textField == self.Field5) {
        [self.Field5 resignFirstResponder];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check that the `textField.delegate = self;` where self is current `UIViewController` is set and then check if you are resigning the textfield by: `[textField resignFirstResponder];`